# How to set a firefox profile to an existing driver object

Tags: java, selenium

I will not create a new driver like this:

`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);`

I want to add the profile to an existing driver instance. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Selenium does create a temporary anonymous profile and associate it with the Driver instance whenever it invokes FirefoxDriver constructor with empty argument and then you need to add your extensions  or user preferences every time as this is temporary profile.

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

To overcome this, you need to create your custom profile and associate the same profile every time when you are instantiating WebDriver object by

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("custom-profile");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

Coming back to your question:

You want to switch from temporary profile to custom profile but there are no methods in firefoxDriver class to do this so to the existing driver instance you cannot associate another custom profile.

Once you have your custom profile, always make sure you call driver.quit method so that it will clean up all temporary files that it creates each time when you instantaite Driver instance.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();     
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("profile");     
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

Comment: Have you created the profile in the firefox browser with the same name?

Comment: WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile); - this overrides the existing driver instance. I don't want to override. I want to extend.

Comment: I have the same requirement, can somebody help me? (but with chrome)